# How to create a child scope from the parent with default dependency injection in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, .net-core, ioc-container

I am building a console .NET Core application. It periodically runs a method that does some work. How do I make ServiceProvider behave in the same way it behaves in ASP.NET Core apps. I want it to resolve scoped services when the method begins it's execution and dispose the resolved services at the end of the method.

```
// pseudocode

globalProvider.AddScoped<ExampleService>();

// ...

using (var scopedProvider = globalProvider.CreateChildScope())
{
    var exampleService = scopedProvider.Resolve<ExampleService>();
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `IServiceProvider.CreateScope()` method to create a local scope:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddScoped<ExampleService>();
var globalProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

using (var scope = globalProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var localScoped = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ExampleService>();

    var globalScoped = globalProvider.GetService<ExampleService>();
}
```

It can be easily tested:

```
using (var scope = globalProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var localScopedV1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ExampleService>();
    var localScopedV2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ExampleService>();
    Assert.Equal(localScopedV1, localScopedV2);

    var globalScoped = globalProvider.GetService<ExampleService>();
    Assert.NotEqual(localScopedV1, globalScoped);
    Assert.NotEqual(localScopedV2, globalScoped);
}
```

Documentation: [Service Lifetimes and Registration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options).

Reference [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) 
or just [Microsoft.AspNetCore.All](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/)
package to use the code above.

Comment: Is it possible to add new dependecies to the scope?

Comment: @t3chb0t no, after `BuildServiceProvider()` call no new registrations can be made.